# Datalabels are missing in dynamic chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, office365, microsoft-excel-2019

I am trying to create a dynamic chart but the data labels are missing. I add the data labels manually to all headers and then save and close the file. When I open the file and select a different header, they go missing again. Only the chart with the active "header" retains the data label. How do I solve this issue?

This is how my data, named ranges and chart connection looks like

**Data**

[image: Data]

**Named ranges**

[image: Named ranges]

**Chart connections**

[image: Chart connections]

**Output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chart is treating the three columns as different series.

Use a formula to copy the data for the selected column into a single column that doesn't change. I have put this formula in G1:

```
=RIGHT($G$10,1)
```

And this formula in G2:

```
=OFFSET(A2:A4,0,G1)
```

I have list data validation in cell G10, similar to you:

[image]

Here, the chart is always using the same range for the data, so it treats it as a single series. As you have added the labels to that series, they are not lost when the data changes.

Comment: Damn! This makes my job super easy. Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Double Damn. I spent 15 minutes preparing a response, which was essentially the same as Flex's, then I actually saw his response. Good job.